# does AWS provides PEAR package manager installation from repository?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, pear

does AWS provides pear package manager installation from repository?

If AWS provides, What is the package name? otherwise please give some pointer on PEAR installation on linux.

```
 #pear channel-discover pear.amazonwebservices.com
 bash: pear: command not found

 # yum install pear
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 Setting up Install Process
 No package pear available.
 Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install pear on your system in two commands:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

Comment: Already installed LAMP, I have php5.6, after install pear I am getting php5.3 version and pear points to php5.3.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but for those who come across it through google like I did you can find details on how to install the aws sdk via pear on [amazon's php pear page](http://pear.amazonwebservices.com/)

essentially you do the following:

```
pear channel-discover pear.amazonwebservices.com

pear install aws/sdk
```